# How is jQuery $(this) used inside event delegation method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to make myself this small jQuery code that tests if the user has entered something. If they haven't, alert them the errors. However, I seem to have a small problem, the keyword `$(this)` in this case doesn't seem to behave as it should. Please help!

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<div id="error-div-1"></div>
<input type="text" id="hobbies" name="hobbies" />
<div id="error-div-2"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showError(i) {
    var errorDivID = "#error-div-" + i;

    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(errorDivID).html("Please enter something!");
    } else {
        $(errorDivID).html("");
    }
}

$("#name").on("blur", function() {
    showError(1);
});

$("#hobbies").on("blur", function() {
    showError(2);
})
```

Comment: That's because the `scope` of `this` is changed. Try `showError.apply(this, [1])`

Comment: You can learn how `this` works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` you refer in `showError()` refers to `window` object; as the function is in the global scope and not in the event handler scope.

Pass it to the function like below,

```
function showError(i, element) {
    var errorDivID = "#error-div-" + i;

    if ($(element).val() === "") {
        $(errorDivID).html("Please enter something!");
    } else {
        $(errorDivID).html("");
    }
}

$("#name").on("blur", function () {
    showError(1, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of your html, it could get even more simple by using  `$(this)` within the call:

```
    $("input").on("blur", function() {
        if($(this).val() === ""){
            $(this).next().html("Please enter something!");
        }else {
            $(this).next().html("");
        }

    });
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eypm8ozj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to pass the **$(this)** to the function.  On that code the value of th **$(this)** is now a callback and not the element anymore.

```
function showError(i, elem) {
    var errorDivID = "#error-div-" + i;

    if (elem.val() === "") {
        $(errorDivID).html("Please enter something!");
    } else {
        $(errorDivID).html("");
    }
}

$("#name").on("blur", function() {
    showError(1, $(this));
});

$("#hobbies").on("blur", function() {
     showError(2, $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` while calling showError method

```
<script>
        function showError(i, element) {
            var errorDivID = "#error-div-" + i;

            if ($(element).val() === "") {
                $(errorDivID).html("Please enter something!");
            } else {
                $(errorDivID).html("");
            }
        }

        $("#name").on("blur", function() {
            showError(1, this);
        });

        $("#hobbies").on("blur", function() {
            showError(2, this);
        })
    </script>
```

OR you can change logic in showError like below

```
<script>
        function showError() {

           if ($(this).val() === "") {
                $(this).next('div').html("Please enter something!");
            } else {
                $(this).next('div').html("");
            }
        }

        $("#name").on("blur", showError);

        $("#hobbies").on("blur", showError);
    </script>
```

You can code your logic like below -

```
$("#name, #hobbies").on("blur", function(){
     if($(this).val()==""){
           $(this).next('div').html("Please enter something!");
     } else {
           $(this).next('div').html("");
     }

  });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n355408s/3/)**

NOTE : - Please uncomment the relevant code snippet to work in JSFiddle Demo link

Comment: How are about `showError(1, this)` can be `showError.call(this, 1)`, So `function showError(i){...}` can stay

Comment: @caoglish, yes you are right. This way OP need not to change showError function. Thanks :). OP please make note of it.

Answer (score 0):

To use this normally, you can use `.call()` to "modify" the scope of the function

```
function showError(i) {
    var errorDivID = "#error-div-" + i;

    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(errorDivID).html("Please enter something!");
    } else {
        $(errorDivID).html("");
    }
}

$("#name").on("blur", function() {
    showError.call(this, 1);
});

$("#hobbies").on("blur", function() {
    showError.call(this, 2);
});
```

This allows your function code to stay the same.

#### More

[**`.call()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) allows you to modify the scope of a function. In simple terms, it allows you to modify the `this` in the function. The reason the `this` isn't passed is because  the function can have it's own private variables and so could the function the function is being called in, this would cause problems. To avoid this, functions don't share the scope with the function they are being called in. With `.call()`, we are setting the `this` object.

#### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/n355408s/)